# What are those vertical lines in Notepad++ called? The ones that light up for matching brackets or tags, etc

Tags: notepad++, gedit

I'd like an actual term for them. Tab lines?

I can't find a reference to them on google because i don't know what to search for!

I wanna see if there's something like this for Gedit.

Comment: People who were looking for Visual Studio just like me, here is the link for VS 2013 : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30

Answer (score 91, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is called the "Indent Guide".

In Notepad++ 5.9.8 on Windows, it is found under View/Show Symbol/Show Indent Guide.

Comment: You saved my day, after some updating these got missing, and I got confused about them. THANK YOU

Answer (score 5):

"Show vertical edge", found under Settings/Preferences/Editing

Comment: This are not the tab lines the asker is talking about. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11641560/8507) correctly points out that they're "Indent Guides".

Comment: It seems the asker saw this summer different, since this answer got accepted.

Comment: Or maybe it was that the right answer wasn't available for almost two years.

Comment: Indeed, "indent guides" is returning more than zero results in Google. Doesn't seem to be any such plugin yet though. I changed the best answer.